# Erro de sintaxe ao compilar no Windows CE

Tags: lazarus, windows-ce

É possível fazer um Browser para windows CE utilizando o Lazarus?

Fiz um com o componente Gecko mas não compilou para windows CE, tem alguma configuração a ser feita ou ele não é suportado mesmo?

Ocorre o seguinte erro:

> Fatal: Syntax error, "identifier" expected but "CONST" found

Alguém sabe como proceder?

O erro é apresentado no arquivo **C:\lazarus\components\geckoport_v1\nsConsts.pas**

Quando compilo para windows 7, ele compila e executa normalmente, mas quando compilo para windows CE é que o erro ocorre.

Nesta linha que ocorre o erro:

```
unit nsConsts;

interface

const
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  XPCOM_DLL = 'xpcom.dll';
  XUL_DLL = 'xul.dll';
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF UNIX}
  XPCOM_DLL = 'libxpcom.so';
  XUL_DLL = 'libxul.so';
{$ENDIF}

const
  GRE_MOZILLA_WIN_REG_LOC = 'Software\mozilla.org\GRE\';
  GRE_FIREFOX_BASE_WIN_REG_LOC = 'SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox';

  // 1.7 Release
  MOZILLA_VERSION = 1.7;
  GRE_BUILD_ID = '1.7_2004061609';
  NS_BUILD_ID = 2004061609;

  // 1.7.1 Release
  //MOZILLA_VERSION = 1.7;
  //GRE_BUILD_ID = '1.7.1_2004070721';
  //NS_BUILD_ID = 2004070721;

  // 1.7.2 Release
  //MOZILLA_VERSION = 1.7;
  //GRE_BUILD_ID = '1.7.2_2004080302';
  //NS_BUILD_ID = 2004080302;

  // 1.7.3 Release
  //MOZILLA_VERSION = 1.7;
  //GRE_BUILD_ID = '1.7.3_2004091008';
  //NS_BUILD_ID = 2004091008;

  // 1.7.5 Release
  //MOZILLA_VERSION = 1.7;
  //GRE_BUILD_ID = '1.7.5_2004122323';
  //NS_BUILD_ID = 2004122323;

  // 1.7.6 Release
  //MOZILLA_VERSION = 1.7;
  //GRE_BUILD_ID = '1.7.6_2005031907';
  //NS_BUILD_ID = 2005031907;

  // 1.7.7 Release
  //MOZILLA_VERSION = 1.7;
  //GRE_BUILD_ID = '1.7.7_2005041417';
  //NS_BUILD_ID = 2005041417;

implementation

end.
```

Comment: Este erro parece ser um erro "generico", poderia mostrar o código o que você fez até agora?

Comment: Editei a pergunta @GuilhermeNascimento com mais informações. O erro ocorre no próprio código do componente.

Comment: O que vem antes de `const`? Pela mensagem de erro o problema ocorre por que ele esperava outra coisa, poste um código que possa ser reproduzido do problema (ou o código o mais inteiro possivel)

Comment: Esta ali todo o código Guilherme, lembrando que o erro ocorre no const acima do GRE_MOZILLA_WIN_REG_LOC

Comment: Amigo a noite irei testar, sim ocorre acima por que o problema é alguma instrução anterior que procura uma coisa mas acha o `const` no meio do caminho, é um erro genérico.